# Do smartglasses where you can see the image being taken exist?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, composition, wifi

I was wondering if there were any smart glasses, or an eyepiece where you could receive the image, in real time, that is being composed on your viewfinder or live View?

I often use awkward angles and tripods and it is often a pita to compose the pictures. I thought that maybe now that many cameras have WiFi and you can see the frame being taken in a phone, that the same could be done directly into the lens of glasses, or projected in a clippable add on lens or something of that sort using Bluetooth or WiFi

Comment: No EVF is real time. There's always at least minimal lag between capture on the sensor and display on a screen.

Comment: none that are perfectly realtime, but there are field monitors (basically small portable screens) that you can attach via hdmi or wireless, or use the vendors app on your phone/laptop/tablet